# pushing strings into an object

Tags: javascript, arrays, javascript-objects

I have an array of objects and an array of string and I am tying to combine the two in sequence meaning I would like to first item on the array to be stored only in the first object, second item of the array only in the second object, ect.  Something like the following.

```
var objects = [ obj1, obj2, obj3];

var strings = ["123", "456", "789"];


//Result
var results = [
    {
      "obj1": {
          number: "123"
      },
    {
      "obj2": {
          number: "456"
      },
    {
      "obj2": {
          number: "789"
      }
    ];
```

I have been trying to do this with a push and a for loop but I seem to end up with each object containing all three strings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its easy:-

```
for (var i = 0; i < objects.length; i++) {// start loop for getting values one by one from object array
  objects[i].number = strings[i]; // assign string values to object array values
}
```

Comment: What's the difference between your and @Fabricator's answer?

Answer (score 2):

Matched object and string share the same array index:

```
for (var i = 0; i < objects.length; i++) {
  objects[i].number = strings[i];
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Or you could do this using the map function:

```
var results = objects.map(function (value, index) { 
    return Object.assign({}, value, { number: strings[index] });
});
```

The other answers are good I just wanted to give you another way. This way you also do not modify the existing objects array

In case you don't know Object.assign add to the first argument (in our case the empty object {}) all the properties from the other object arguments. You can read more about it here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign 
Also, you can learn here about the map function: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map